# Proof of Hopf's theorem (the one about cohomology of Lie groups being equal to the cohomology of a product of spheres)

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homology-cohomology

> Theorem (H. Hopf). Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group. Then $G$ has the real cohomology of a product of odd dimensional spheres,
>   $H(G,\mathbb{R}) \approx H(\prod_q S^{2k_q - 1},\mathbb{R})$.

The only place I could find the proof of this theorem was the book by Greub, *Connections, curvature and cohomology*. Do you guys know where else can I find a proof of this theorem? The original papers are in german and french, and I couldn't find any translations. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is a corollary of Theorem 3C.4 in [Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html):

> If $A$ is a [connected graded] commutative, associative Hopf algebra over a field $F$ of
>   characteristic 0, and $A^n$ is finite-dimensional over $F$ for each $n$, then $A$ is isomorphic as an algebra to the tensor product of an exterior algebra on odd-dimensional generators and a polynomial algebra on even-dimensional generators.

The cohomology of a compact connected Lie group is a Hopf algebra satisfying these conditions, and additionally is $0$ in all but finitely degrees.  This means that there cannot be any even-dimensional generators, so you have an exterior algebra on odd-dimensional generators, which is isomorphic to the cohomology ring of $\prod_q S^{2k_q-1}$ where the numbers $2k_q-1$ are the dimensions of the generators.

Comment: May I ask if the following refinement of the result stated above holds : Assume that the cohomology ring of a compact connected Lie group has n generators all concentrated in degree 1, then can one say that the compact connected Lie group is in fact isomorphic to product of $S^1$? Perhaps something weaker is true? Please let me know if it is more appropriate to ask a separate question. Thanks!

Comment: I think that's probably true but don't know how to prove it off the top of my head.  Asking it as a separate question would make sense.